# Regex - CSV email addresses ok, but how to prevent ending with comma?

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm using the jQuery .validate plugin. I have written a custom rule to allow comma separated email addresses which looks like this:

```
$.validator.addMethod('csvEmail', function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^((([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))+(,|, |$))*$/.test(value);
        }, "Please enter a valid email address or multiple valid addresses separated by a comma.");
```

This works for: `test@test.com, example@test.com` and also the same without the space in the middle.

But this is where I am stuck because it also works for: `test@test.com,` and there is my problem.

Which part of the regex needs to change to disallow a valid email address ending with a comma?

Comment: Regex for email address is not that simple, Please, have a look at these sites:  [valid/invalid addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Examples); [regex for RFC822 email address](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final part of the expression is:

```
)+(,|, |$))*$
```

Note that `,|,` is equivalent to `, ?` (or perhaps `,\s*` to be more flexible).

One way to prevent the trailing comma is with a negative lookahead:

```
)+(,\s?(?!$)|$))*$
```

This says "match comma followed by optional space but only if not followed by end of input".

The more normal way to do things would be with a different construction `A(BA)*` instead of `(A(B|$))*` but clearly that repetition would be error-prone here!

Comment: I just learned about negative look behinds myself. I've altered the end to `(?<!,|, )$`

Answer (score 1):

let's go by parts... first how to get a valid domain element.  It is made of alphanumeric strings that can include a hyphen in between two characters but not at the ends, nor repeated.  This can be done with this regexp:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*
```

you see, as the hyphen is optional, alphanumeric strings with no hyphen are allowed to any length, they cannot be at any end and no hyphen can be repeated (hyphen is always surrounded by an alphanumeric.  This will form a domain component, to have one or more domain components separated by dots... we use the same approach and write:

```
<EXP>(\.<EXP>)*
```

where `<EXP>` is the regexp above.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)*
```

this will match the domain part of an email address.  To form the rest we allow any character (except `@`,  and `,`) because they are used to separate components:

```
[^@,\s]+
```

so our regex leads to:

```
[^@,\s]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)*
```

and then we allow any repetition of these, separated with `\s*,\s*` (a comma surrounded by any number of spaces):

```
<EXP>(\s*,\s*<EXP>)*
```

where `<EXP>` is the expression above:

```
[^@,\s]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)*(\s*,\s*[^@,\s]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*(\.[a-zA-Z0-9](-?[a-zA-Z0-9])*)*)*
```

will be an expression that will parse all, as you want.  See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/O2r5iD/1) for a demonstration on how it works.

It seems complex, but you have only to write it only once.

Expect that this helps.